# PHP force assign by value

Tags: php, object, reference, copy

I have

```
$today = new DateTime();
$tomorrow = $today->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
$day = $tomorrow;
$day->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
```

After this, `$day` will have the reference of `$tomorrow,` which means, if I change `$day` like this:

```
$day->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
```

then also the $tomorrow will change to day after tomorrow:

```
print_r($tomorrow);
```

, and I don't want that.

For now the only solution I found to copy object by value is:

```
$day = clone $tomorrow;
```

but I don't like this. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Use DateTimeImmutable

Comment: Using `clone` is the right way if you want to keep your first variable and an other with the DateInterval. I'm using it too.

Comment: `but I don't like this`...because? It's hard to suggest what to do (if anything) when we don't understand what problem you have with with the standard approach. You need a technical reason, not just an opinion or coding style preference.

Comment: @AD yeah you know, I just don't like it....that's it. Would prefer another way to do this.

Comment: @hamham thanks. I see it is correct but I would like another approach to this.

Comment: As @JohnConde already suggested, `DateTimeImmutable` is a viable option. Just note that if you use it, `$day->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));` would not cause `$day` or `$tomorrow` to be modified. You'd have to store the result into a variable, which would then hold the new, modified instance.

Comment: @El_Vanja this actually sounds like a very good alternative. If someone puts that as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score -1):

Create two separate objects.

```php
$today = new DateTime();
$tomorrow = new DateTime();
$tomorrow->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
```